# Android studio error in debug

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem with android studio. I start debug and I read this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\Já-Programování\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Já-Programování\AndroidStudioProjects\sharer\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\Já-Programování\AndroidStudioProjects\sharer\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       1
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: C:\Users\JÃ¡-ProgramovÃ¡nÃ­\AndroidStudioProjects\sharer\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug: file not found
>           at com.android.dex.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:51)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:169)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\JÃ¡-ProgramovÃ¡nÃ­\AndroidStudioProjects\sharer\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-22.2.0-f6d91f10d9ed6a0fbf608132190b5427097e8403.jar (Systém nem?že nalézt uvedenou cestu)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\JÃ¡-ProgramovÃ¡nÃ­\AndroidStudioProjects\sharer\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-22.2.0-a76b6178813c2e8cf3ea12aeac1aff6c3e61b683.jar (Systém nem?že nalézt uvedenou cestu)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\JÃ¡-ProgramovÃ¡nÃ­\AndroidStudioProjects\sharer\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-5507b33e9c3f118a9ade6c0f1008f42c1ef31ab6.jar (Systém nem?že nalézt uvedenou cestu)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\JÃ¡-ProgramovÃ¡nÃ­\AndroidStudioProjects\sharer\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-dff895965e0b2e1d976e53adb386d9b4cec47b37.jar (Systém nem?že nalézt uvedenou cestu)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>       5 errors; aborting
>   Please help!

Answer (score -1):

Please, check if the following file is present:

C:\Users\JÃ¡-ProgramovÃ¡nÃ­\AndroidStudioProjects\sharer\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-dff895965e0b2e1d976e53adb386d9b4cec47b37.jar

If the file exists, then the system cannot read its location. Probably an issue with your language char encode.
If "Systém nemůže nalézt uvedenou cestu" is czech, then the system is likely using the wrong encode for the path

Or, check the line 106 in your com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106) class.
Check if its linking to an actual file, or paste the commands given on your question

Comment: `com.android.dx.command.Main` is the android dexer, not the OP's program. `build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-dff895965e0b2e1d976e53adb386d9b4cec47b37.jar` is a file generated by the previous step of the build.